# R: Appling functions(Shapiro test) for different conditions to each column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have questions for applying functions for each column of my dataframe.

What I am willing to do is applying shapiro.test, levene.test and pair.t.test,

by condition to each column(sp1,sp2...)
for example, I want to apply shapiro.test by condition to sp1 column, and do the same thing to all other columns.
I first tried to solve it with lapply, but dont know how to do it by conditions...

Here is part of my data frame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdywP.png)

It seems to the matter of apply family functions to me, but I have no idea for sure... Please help noobs for R!

Comment: use dput(df[1:3,]) and copy that output into your post. It will help the community replicate your problem more easily.

Comment: thanks! I changed it to image so that looks more intuitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go. I'm sure it could be done in a better way, but this might be able to help you get started. If this answers your question, please mark it as so.

Best of luck,
NF

```
conds_vec<- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "control"), each=30)
set.seed(1234)
sp1<- stats::runif(n = length(conds_vec), min = 1, max = 10)
sp2<- base::sample(x=1:25, size = length(conds_vec), replace = TRUE)
sp3<- stats::rnorm(n=length(conds_vec), mean = 3, sd = 3)

df<- data.frame(condition=conds_vec, sp1=sp1, sp2=sp2, sp3=sp3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
## This is the split-apply-combine paradigm here
# Step 1. Generate splits on the condition column (generates a list of data.frames)
splits<- split(df, df$condition)
sapply(splits, class) # just a list of data.frames

# Step 2. Apply a function, i.e. shapiro.wilk, to each column other than the 'condition' column 
# We'll define these columns as those with a numeric or interger type
numeric_col_indicies<-  which(sapply(df, class) %in% c("numeric", "integer"))

# For DEV, to help with understanding what's happening under the hood
#x<- 1
#y<- 1
# How long is the list of splits? (4), so let's do something for each element in the sequence
seq_along(splits)
stat_test_lists<- lapply(seq_along(splits), function(x){
  mini_df<- splits[[x]]
  tmp<- lapply(seq_along(numeric_col_indicies), function(y){
    # We can return the whole stat test object here,
    # or if we wanted to return just the p.values, pull those out of the stat test object and return that
    # Returning the whole thing for now
    stats::shapiro.test(mini_df[, numeric_col_indicies[y]])
  })
  names(tmp)<- colnames(df)[numeric_col_indicies]
  return(tmp)
})
length(stat_test_lists)
# Give the big list some pretty names, these come from the conditions and are the same as the names in the splits list
names(stat_test_lists)<- names(splits)
# What are those names?
lapply(stat_test_lists, names)
# Look at the top level information about the structure of the stat_test_lists object
str(stat_test_lists, max.level = 1)
# Dig a little deeper
str(stat_test_lists, max.level = 2)
# See all the nitty-gritty details
str(stat_test_lists)


## Step 3: Combine. Let's put the values for the statistic and the p.value into the original data frame (this will give us a bunch of ugly duplicated values)
## OR...maybe we just want to make our own pretty dataframe of results
stat_test_vals<- lapply(seq_along(stat_test_lists), function(x){
  tmpx<- stat_test_lists[[x]]
  condition_value<- names(stat_test_lists)[x]
  pvals<- lapply(tmpx, function(y){y$p.value})
  statistic_values<- lapply(tmpx, function(y){y$statistic})
  # Make them data frames, assign better names
  tmp_p<- as.data.frame(pvals)
  names(tmp_p)<- paste0(names(tmp_p), "_p_val")
  tmp_sv<- as.data.frame(statistic_values)
  names(tmp_sv)<- paste0(names(tmp_sv), "_stat_val")
  # Build output dataframe
  out<- data.frame(condition=condition_value, tmp_sv, tmp_p, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  rownames(out)<- NULL
  return(out)
})

stat_test_res<- do.call("rbind", stat_test_vals)

## We could now merge the results back into our original data frame if desired (not likely..but just for fun)

df<- base::merge(df, stat_test_res, by.x="condition", by.y="condition")
head(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much nate !  This frame code will be a big help! Sorry for late reply...